# Understanding Actor-Advantage Critic

Tags: python, c++, neural-network, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I am attempting to implement an A2C neural network in C++ from [this tutorial](https://github.com/rgilman33/simple-A2C/blob/master/3_A2C-nstep-TUTORIAL.ipynb). I could only find Python tutorials and this Python tutorial made the most sense to me.

I have already implemented a regular back propagation neural network, however, I want to upgrade this to use reinforcement learning. I have created a C++ version of the Pytorch `Tensor` and most other things necessary to complete this. I'm having issues going about implementing their `Variable` class. I've read over the [docs](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/autograd.html?highlight=backward#torch.autograd.Variable) and understand the concept of [automatic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation) using the chain rule, but I'm unsure on how to convert `Tensor`s into `Variable`s and what all needs to happen behind the scenes. I might even already have all the necessary gradient math with my original backprop neural network implementation.

It has been very difficult trying to decipher the Python code (I don't have a background in Python) especially since I had to guess the types of complex variables (`Variable` vs `Tensor` vs `Vector`, etc.). For example, I don't understand the line `total_loss.backward()` (section `In [4]:` of the tutorial). Is `total_loss` not a double (or float)? My `mean()` function of `Tensor` returns a single value representing the mean of the entire `Tensor`. `total_loss` is just simple operations done on floats or doubles. But, then it calls `backward()` on it. I found three `backward`s but unsure which one since none make sense in the context. [`torch.autograd.backward`](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/autograd.html?highlight=backward#torch.autograd.backward), [`torch.autograd.Function.backward`](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/autograd.html?highlight=backward#torch.autograd.Function.backward), and [`torch.autograd.Variable.backward`](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/autograd.html?highlight=backward#torch.autograd.Variable.backward). None of which make sense because `total_loss` is a double, right?

Another missing step is the "forward" and "backward" pass implementations. The tutorial says Pytorch does the backward pass for me, but as I am in C++, I need to do that implementation myself and I'm not too sure the purpose of the different passes. Are these the feeding forward and back propagation of neural networks?

I'm also confused about the `optim` and how it is doing stochastic optimization. I've read the [docs](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/optim.html#torch.optim.Adam) on that too but I am still not certain on how that converts to C++. I know it's a first-order gradient-based optimization of stochastic objective functions based on adaptive estimates of lower-order moments.

From what I have researched over the past few weeks, I need to create a forward accumulation computational graph of tensors as nodes with the chain rule performed on the tensor data in order to fix the dependent variable to compute the derivatives with respect to each sub-expression on the nodes recursively. Then, use automatic differentiation of the arbitrary scalar valued functions (which are the neural network activation functions?) to propagate through the tree and result in the respective gradients. The chain rule differentiates the graph and each node would hold the w.r.t value and the function that created it.

I think I am fine for the concepts for the majority of the implementation, just how to go about programming it is a struggle as I don't fully understand how the inter-workings of Python is working.

I've also researched how the implementation of `Variable` looks in the [Pytorch source](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/csrc/autograd/variable.cpp) and read through examples in the [examples section](http://https:://github.com/jcjohnson/pytorch-examples#pytorch-variables-and-autograd), however I am still struggling to understand implementation.

In conclusion (so it doesn't get flagged as too broad), what details do I need to know about Pytorch `Variable` in order to make an implementation in C++, assuming the concept of automatic differentiation is understood? Does it just need to hold a double for gradient and function pointer for activation? Also, how do the `model.variables()` in Python work and get passed around? This is so I can understand how to do the Adam algorithm implementation.

If you need to see code I have already, I can post some, but chose not to currently as the code I already have written doesn't necessarily directly pertain the the questions I have.